# Page transition is slow and overlapping with ionic Angular routing in ionic 5

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular2-routing

I am using the below methods of ionic 5 Navigation Controller for page navigation

```
1) this.navCtrl.navigateForward(path);
2) this.navCtrl.navigateBack(path);
```

But the page navigation is not smooth like push or pop in ionic 3 and pages are overlapping sometimes. Please help me to sort this out

Comment: See if using Angular's router to navigate will clear up your issues `this.router.navigate([path])`. That's what Ionic recommends https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/navigation#navigating-to-different-routes

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But still the page is overlapping when navigating forward

Comment: Do you have any resolver for pages?

Comment: No, just static page navigation with some cards is also overlapping

Comment: Hard to diagnose without a full reproduction of the problem. It's unclear at this point what's wrong.